# Designing popovers in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have created a navigation controller and its child controllers in storyboard (Interface Builder). These controllers are being presented inside a popover only.

The bar button which will present the popover is created in code and will be added to the toolbar programmatically.

This works basically fine. However, the size of the view controllers in storyboard are standard iPad size, which makes designing the UI very hard as the view controllers presented in the popovers will be much smaller.

How can I adjust the size of view controllers designed in storyboard directly in Interface Builder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the view controller's size property to "Freeform" then click on the view and adjust the size of the view to the size you desire.

Comment: Thank you, HackyStack! This works fine for the child view controllers. But how can I set the size for navigation controller? It does not have its own view.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's no way to resize a navigation controller that I'm aware of.  As you mentioned, it has no view, so why would it matter anyway???

Comment: It would take less space on storyboard. But that is not too important. :-)